# Adding image to HTML/PDF report

Tags: cuba-platform

I'm trying to add an image in an HTML report template. The image is stored in sys$FileDescriptor. I found some instructions for docx templates, but no luck so far with html templates.

I also tried using FileDescriptor.name as src field, but the file specified doesn't exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I managed to insert an image in an html template for pdf generation with this code:

```
<img src="../work/app-core/filestorage/${headerRow.fields.logoYear}/${headerRow.fields.logoMonth}/${headerRow.fields.logoDay}/${headerRow.fields.logoId}.${headerRow.fields.logoExt}" width="220" height="220"/>
```

The needed fields are obtained in sql from sys_file.update_ts with "to_char" Postgres function to allow for the correct format of the fields (YYYY, MM, DD)

Answer (score 1):

At the moment YARG and CUBA Reporting do not provide means to insert images into HTML-reports similarly to DOCX/XLSX.

But pictures could be inserted/embedded with the `img`-tag. 
`src` could be a link to picture:

```
<img src="http://localhost:8080/images/SomePicture.jpg" height="68" width="199" border="0" align="right"/>
```

Or you can embed a bitmap (your appproach with variables is also useable):

```
<img alt='SomePicture.png' src='data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0K ..... AcEP9PwxD0hNKK1FCAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC' style='max-width: 100%;'/>
```

Thank you for your question. The platform documentation is going to be updated soon.